# How can I plot a function of NSolve results?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

A seemingly simple question. I have an equation with a free parameter. There is no explicit solution, so I plot the numerical solutions as functions of the parameter.

```
Plot[x /. 
  NSolve[
   d == 1/
      4 (3 - 2 (1.5 - x)*E^(-2 (2 - x)) + E^(-2 (1.5 - x)) - 
        4*E^(-(3.5 - 2 x))) && x < 2, x, Reals], {d, 0.1, 0.5}]
```

But what I really want to see is a function of the result. Something like

```
E^(NSolve[expr,vars])
```

How can I do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use exact constants

```
eqn = d == 
    1/4 (3 - 2 (1.5 - x)*E^(-2 (2 - x)) + E^(-2 (1.5 - x)) - 
       4*E^(-(3.5 - 2 x))) // Rationalize // Simplify

(* (-3 + 4 d) E^4 + 4 E^(1/2 + 2 x) + E^(2 x) (3 - 2 x) == 
  E^(1 + 2 x) *)
```

The exact real solution for `x < 2`

```
f[d_] = SolveValues[
    eqn && x < 2, x, Reals, Method -> Reduce][[1]] //
  Simplify
```

[image]

Graphically,

```
Legended[
 Show[
  ContourPlot[
   Evaluate@eqn, {d, -1, 1}, {x, -2, 4},
   ContourStyle -> Lighter@Green],
  Plot[f[d], {d, f[d][[-1, 1]], f[d][[-1, -1]]},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed},
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   MaxRecursion -> 15],
  GridLines -> {{3/4}, {2}},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {d, x})],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[{Lighter@Green, {Red, Dashed}},
   {HoldForm@eqn, HoldForm@f[d]}],
  {0.4, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Plotting functions of `f[d]`

```
Plot[{E^f[d], f[d]^2}, {d, 0, 3/4},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.5, 0.7}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To use `NSolve` rather than `Solve`

```
Clear[eqn]

eqn[d_] = FullSimplify /@
   (d == 1/
        4 (3 - 2 (1.5 - x)*E^(-2 (2 - x)) + E^(-2 (1.5 - x)) - 
         4*E^(-(3.5 - 2 x))) // Rationalize);

f2[d_?NumericQ] := NSolveValues[eqn[d] && x < 2, x, Reals][[1]]
```

Plotting is much slower:

```
Plot[Evaluate@{E^f2[d], f2[d]^2}, {d, 0, 3/4},
  WorkingPrecision -> 15, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.5, 0.7}]] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It does work. However, it seems that the validity relies on the fact that the original function can be solved using SolveValues. When the equation becomes more complicated, SolveValues returns: 

"SolveValues was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help."

But simultaneously NSolve can still give any d a unique solution.

Comment: See edit for use of `NSolve`